# Python doesn't detect the library

Tags: python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, langchain, ubuntu-22.04, ollama

I am new in Python and I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/quickstart#building-with-langchain).

I am using `Python 3.12.2`.

I followed until the end of [Retrieval Chain](https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/quickstart#retrieval-chain).

I am running it using `ollama` to run it locally.

But when I tried to run my `main.py` file I got the following error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myUser/repos/python/myFirstProject/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from langchain_community.llms import Ollama
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_community'
```

My environment is active and all the packages are installed in the environment, because when I run `pip list` shows all the packages installed and there is the `langchain-community`:
|Package|Version|
|-|-|
|other packages...|x.x.x|
|langchain|0.1.13|
|langchain-cli|0.0.21|
|langchain-community|0.0.29|
|langchain-core|0.1.34|
|langchain-text-splitters|0.0.1|
|langserve|0.0.51|
|langsmith|0.1.33|
|other packages...|x.x.x|

I tried reinstalling the packages again but still have the same result.

I am using `PyCharm` and all of the packages mentioned before are in the folder: `.venv/include/lib/python3.12/site-packages`. Even when I go to `file -> settings -> Project:myProjectName -> Python Interpreter` it shows the same `Python` version in the interpreter and it list all of the packages installed.

I am using `wsl2`, `Ubuntu-22.04` and `PyCharm` got the interpreter from there, so I don't think those thinks are the problem.